# Creating a class that implements tabs and can be used as a "central widget" in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I want the central widget of my `mainWindow` class to be a `QTabWidget`. My plan is to create widgets that I want to put in the tabs as separate classes and add them to `QTabWidget` class and add the `QtabWidget` class itself as a central Widget to the `mainWindow` class.

To do this, how must I declare my tabWidget class ?

Should it be :

```
class centralTab : public QMainWindow
{

}
```

or

```
class centralTab : public QDialog
{

}
```

Also, in the ctor, What should be used as the parent ?

Comment: Why do you want to create your own class? What do you benefit from it?

Comment: @msrd0 I am not trying to create a class that creates tabs. Simply one that _uses_ QTabWidgets and _implements_ tabs.

Comment: centralTab will have QTabWidget member that will do all the Tabbing work.

Comment: Ah okay, do you use QtCreator/QtDesigner or do you want to create the class on your own?

Comment: I am using QtCreator, but I really want to do it on my own. Think it is better since I am learning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create `QMainWindow` subclass:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
//...
};
```

In constructor use `addTab()` method::

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent)
{
        QTabWidget *tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
        //some settings
        tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("example1"), "General1");
        tabWidget->addTab(new QLabel("example2"), "General2");
        setCentralWidget(tabWidget);
}
```

Why `QMainWindow`? Because only `QMainWindow` has `setCentralWidget()` method;

You can add different widgets and set also icon to every tab, `QLabel` is just example.

Comment: What about `centralTab` ? Does it need to inherit from `QMainWindow` if it needs to be used as a centralWidget ?

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying. I don't need the centralTab class at all right ? I can simply create different widgets in different classes and keep adding them to this tab as I wish. Right ?

Comment: @Wildling Yes, of course.see my edit please, I added small example.

Comment: `ui->tabWidget` automatically corresponds to the `centralWidget` of `QMainWindow` class ?

Comment: @Wildling I should not do this, see my edit, now it is in one code snippet(it works)